# Yii 2 signup does not save records

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

In first, sorry for my bad English, I am little bit tried... 
My problem is that, when iI want to create a new user everything goes well, but ActiveRecord does not save my new account.

This is my first question.. don't realy know what to paste in here... But:

Here is My signup view:

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model \frontend\models\SignupForm */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$this->title = 'Signup';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="site-signup">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>Please fill these forms with the correct informations:</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup']); ?>

               <?= $form->field($model, 'firstname')->textInput() ?>
               <?= $form->field($model, 'lastname')->textInput() ?>
               <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>
               <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput() ?>

               <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the signupForm model:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use common\models\User;

/**
 * Signup form
 */
class SignupForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $email;
    public $password;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            ['firstname', 'required', 'message'=>'You need to fill this'],
            ['firstname','string', 'min'=> 1, 'max'=>30],
            ['lastname', 'required', 'message'=>'You need to fill this'],
            ['lastname','string', 'min'=> 1, 'max'=>30],

            ['username', 'trim'],
            ['username', 'required'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

            ['email', 'trim'],
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

            ['password', 'required'],
            ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return User|null the saved model or null if saving fails
     */
    public function signup()
    {
        if (!$this->validate()) {

        $user = new User();
        $user->firstname = $this->firstname;
        $user->lastname = $this->lastname;
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->save();
        return $user;
    }
        return null;
    }



    public function sendEmail(){   
        $user = User::findOne([
        'status_id' => User::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        'email' => $this->email,
        ]);
        if ($user) {
        $user->generatePasswordResetToken();
        if ($user->save()) {
        return Yii::$app->mailer->compose('passwordResetToken',
        ['user' => $user])
        ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
        ->setTo($this->email)
        ->setSubject('Password reset for ' . Yii::$app->name)
        ->send();
            }
        }
    return false;

    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
        $name = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
        return $this->render('index',['name' => $name]);
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        $this->layout ='login';
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->redirect('?r=site%2Fhome');;
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs out the current user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail']))
            {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'There was an error sending your message.');
            }

            return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            return $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSignup(){
        $model = new SignupForm();
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                    if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                        return $this->goHome();
                    }
                }
            }
        return $this->render('signup', ['model' => $model,]);
    }

    /**
     * Requests password reset.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionRequestPasswordReset()
    {
        $model = new PasswordResetRequestForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');

                return $this->goHome();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to reset password for the provided email address.');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('requestPasswordResetToken', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Resets password.
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return mixed
     * @throws BadRequestHttpException
     */
    public function actionResetPassword($token)
    {
        try {
            $model = new ResetPasswordForm($token);
        } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->resetPassword()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'New password saved.');

            return $this->goHome();
        }

        return $this->render('resetPassword', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And if you don't mind i have one more question... 
How can I make and index page like this? ... I can't call anything into the index file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SDS9.jpg

I created something what i want to saw.

And somebody can link an explanition how to make " list " page for every registred user?

Thank you very much guys..
I know it's pretty much, but I am tilted.

Comment: Change if (!$this->validate()) { for         if ($this->validate()) { in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @nicolascolman said in the comment up first change

```
public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
...
```

to

```
public function signup()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
...
```

**How to make "list" page for every registered user**

For manage creation of user and assign roles or privilages I recommend you to try this extension module: [mdmsoft/yii2-admin](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin)

Here you can find a simply guide for install and configure it:

[Yii 2.0: Installation guide: Yii-2 advanced template with RBAC system](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/848/installation-guide-yii-2-advanced-template-with-rbac-system/)

Comment: In "list page" i meant to like on twitter or Facebook, where you have your own profile page and you can share your " ideas" as post.


Edit: I have a little RBAC System builded up. I have roles as user, admin and SU and i Made statuses for paid and free users. Every user can make a profile, but it shows in grid view.. 
As admin from backend I can update or delete their posts..... 

It is just a TEST app, where i want to learn how to make these "basic" actions in Yii.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the goal you want to achive?

Comment: I made some fancy MS paint stuff 

https://imgsafe.org/image/55f56893dd

Comment: I can't write code for you XD Just help but i can't build an entire structure.

Comment: Look at this extension i just see it has a profile page manger: https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user